# Javabat Help: alarmClock

Tags: java

I am working through the JavaBat questions and am confused about my logic.

Here's the task:

> Given a day of the week encoded as 0=Sun, 1=Mon, 2=Tue, ...6=Sat, and
>   a boolean indicating if we are on vacation, return a string of the
>   form "7:00" indicating when the alarm clock should ring. Weekdays, the
>   alarm should be "7:00" and on the weekend it should be "10:00". Unless
>   we are on vacation -- then on weekdays it should be "10:00" and
>   weekends it should be "off".
>
> alarmClock(1, false) → "7:00" alarmClock(5, false) → "7:00"
>   alarmClock(0, false) → "10:00"

Here's my code:

```
            public String alarmClock(int day, boolean vacation) {
                if ( (day >=1 && day <=5) && (!vacation)) {
                    return "7:00";
                } else if ( (day >=1 && day <=5) && (vacation)) {
                    return "10:00";  
                } else {
                return "off";
                }  
            }
```

Why do these two tests fail?

alarmClock(0, false) → "10:00"  "off"   X
alarmClock(6, false) → "10:00"  "off"   X

Surely, this line covers it?

if (day >=1 && day <=5) && (!vacation))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

how about this?

```
      public String alarmClock(int day, boolean vacation) {
            if (day >=1 && day <=5) {
                return vacation ? "10:00" : "7:00";
            } else {
                return vacation ? "off" : "10:00";
            }  
        }
```

Note it does depend if your coding convention allows the use of the turnary operator. But in this case I think the logic is easier to read.

Answer (score 1):

> Surely, this line covers it?
>
> ```
> if ((day >=1 && day <=5) && (!vacation))
> ```

No, that line doesn't cover it.  If the day is Sunday or Saturday (0 or 6), the first part of your "and" expression `(day >=1 && day <=5)` will be false, since 0 and 6 are not between 1 and 5 inclusive.

The only branch that handles days `0` and `6` is your `else` branch: "off".

This is a great time to use helper methods to express your logic closer to the English description:

```
if ( isWeekday(day) ) {
    if ( vacation ) {
       //what to return here?
    } else {
       //what to return here?
    }
} else {
    if ( vacation ) {
       //what to return here?
    } else {
       //what to return here?
    }
}
```

Then you just need to implement `isWeekday`:

```
private boolean isWeekday(int day) {
   return /*fill this in*/;
}
```

Comment: Why is that? I read the statement (day >=1 && day <=5) as:         "If the day is between 1-6".

Comment: @user: `<=` means "less than or equal to."  Do you believe that 6 is "less than or equal to" 5?

Answer (score 0):

Although the ternary operator is useful here, as this problem can be done in a single return statement, the following code below allows readability.

```
public String alarmClock(int day, boolean vacation) {
      if(vacation){ //if we are on vacation
         if(day > 0 && day < 6){ //if it is weekday and we are on vacation
         return "10:00";
         }
         else return "off"; //it must be the weekend!
      } 
      //from here on out all the cases where vacation is true have been weeded out
      if(day > 0 && day < 6){
      return "7:00";
      }
      else return "10:00";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if ((day == 0 || day == 6) && (!vacation) || (day >= 1 && day <= 5) && (vacation)) {
        return "10:00";
    }
    if ((day >= 1 && day <= 5) && (!vacation)) {
        return "7:00";
    }

    return "off";
```

Answer (score -1):

```
public String alarmClock(int day, boolean vacation) {

  if (((day==0)||(day==6))&&(!vacation)){
  return "10:00";
  }
  else if (((day!=0)||(day!=6))&&(!vacation)){
  return "7:00";
  }
  else if (((day==0)||(day==6))&&(vacation)){
  return "off";
  }
  else{
  return "10:00";
  }




}
```

Comment: Can you add some explanation, please?

Comment: Certainly this is low quality, but it's an attempt to answer the question, so I'm marking it as OK.